# Построение логики включения кнопок

Tags: java, android, button

Есть 4 кнопки: 2 родительские(s1 и s2) и 2 дочерние (s3 и s4) и 2 состояния (on/off).

1. Если s3 или s4 включены, то автоматически включается s1.
2. Если s1 выключена, а s2 включена(и наоборот), то s3 и s4 остаются включёнными.
3. Если родительские кнопки выключены, то и дочерние тоже выключаются.

Код на включение s1 дочерними кнопками:

```
 if (switch3.isChecked()){
           switch1.setChecked(true);
       }
       else{
           switch3.setChecked(false);
       }
        if (switch4.isChecked()){
            switch1.setChecked(true);
        }
        else{
            switch4.setChecked(false);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Проблема то у чём у вас?

Comment: В приведённом коде, первое условие не выполняется. Должно быть ' if (switch3.isChecked() && switch4.isChecked()){
           switch1.setChecked(true);
       }
       else{
           switch1.setChecked(false);
       }'

Answer (score 0):

```
if (bt1.isChecked || bt2.isChecked){
 bt3.setChecked(true);
 bt4.setChecked(true);
}
else if (bt3.isChecked || bt4.isChecked && !bt1.isChecked ){
 bt1.setChecked(true);
}
else{
 bt3.setChecked(false);
 bt4.setChecked(false);
}
```

Не забудьте сохранить состояние кнопки если это требуется !`